# Add double quotes to JSON input using groovy script

Tags: json, groovy

I'm working with Json file and the json structure is incorrectly formatted. I would like to add double quotes (") in the below JSON using groovy scripting.

Input File:

{"I_BEGDA":2020-01-01,"I_ENDDA":2020-01-21,"I_TOTAL":"X"}

Expected Output:

{"I_BEGDA":"2020-01-01","I_ENDDA":"2020-01-21","I_TOTAL":"X"}

I tried multiple scripts but none of them looks working. Appreciate your help in fixing the same.

Thanks

Comment: You could try to use JsonSlurper with LAX type to parse this kind of json then JsonBuilder to format it back to json.

Comment: Did you see my answer? I hope it works for you. If this solution works and no other answers are given, it's customary for the asker to select it as the best answer. If you LIKE the solution, it is customary to upvote it also. But it is more important **to the community** (than me getting the "correct" and "upvote" points) to know whether or not this solved your problem. Please let us know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def input ='{"I_BEGDA":2020-01-01,"I_ENDDA":2020-01-21,"I_TOTAL":"X"}'
def output = new JsonBuilder(
    new JsonSlurper().with { it.type = JsonParserType.LAX ; it }.parseText(input)
)
println(output)
```